# MVC Authentication and Antiforgery token with Durandal SPA template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, durandal

Some areas of my SPA need to be open to all users, and some areas require authentication. In these areas, it's the data loaded via AJAX that I want to protect.

I have an authentication service (see below), which I add as a dependency in my durandal **main.js**. The service is called:

```
authentication
```

In my **main.js** I call

```
authentication.handleUnauthorizedAjaxRequest(function () {
        app.showMessage('You are not authorized, please login')
        .then(function () {
            router.navigateTo('#/user/login');
        });
    });
```

It warns the user they are not authorized, and navigates user to a login view/viewmodel where they can enter details and try logging in.

Some questions that come to mind when building this authentication viewModel:

- Are there any obvious concerns with what I'm doing?
- Is this how I'm 'meant' to do things in Durandal?
- Am I re-inventing the wheel?  I couldn't see anything like this within Durandal.

Most people seem to be creating seperate **cshtml** pages; one for login (if the user is not authenticated), and the usual **index.cshtml** Is there any good reasons for me to switch to that method?

My login action on my the server-side 'user controller' has the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute I need to send that as well.
I also have an 'antiforgery' service (see below) which I also add as a dependency in my **main.js** viewModel file
then (also in my main.js).

```
antiforgery.addAntiForgeryTokenToAjaxRequests();
```

This intercepts all ajax requests (along with content), and adds the MVC AntiForgeryToken value to the data. 
Seems to work exactly as I want it to. Please let me know if there's any errors/mistakes.

Complete authentication service below.

```
// services/authentication.js
define(function (require) {
    var system = require('durandal/system'),
    app = require('durandal/app'),
    router = require('durandal/plugins/router');

    return {
        handleUnauthorizedAjaxRequests: function (callback) {
            if (!callback) {
                return;
            }
            $(document).ajaxError(function (event, request, options) {
                if (request.status === 401) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        },

        canLogin: function () {         
            return true;
        },
        login: function (userInfo, navigateToUrl) {
            if (!this.canLogin()) {
                return system.defer(function (dfd) {
                    dfd.reject();
                }).promise();
            }
            var jqxhr = $.post("/user/login", userInfo)
                .done(function (data) {
                    if (data.success == true) {
                        if (!!navigateToUrl) {
                            router.navigateTo(navigateToUrl);
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return data;
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (data) {
                    return data;
                });

            return jqxhr;
        }
    };
});

// services/antiforgery.js
define(function (require) {
    var app = require('durandal/app');

    return {
        /*  this intercepts all ajax requests (with content)
            and adds the MVC AntiForgeryToken value to the data
            so that your controller actions with the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute won't fail

            original idea came from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074199/jquery-ajax-calls-and-the-html-antiforgerytoken

            to use this

            1) ensure that the following is added to your Durandal Index.cshml
            <form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            </form>

            2) in  main.js ensure that this module is added as a dependency

            3) in main.js add the following line
            antiforgery.addAntiForgeryTokenToAjaxRequests();

        */
        addAntiForgeryTokenToAjaxRequests: function () {
            var token = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm     input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
            if (!token) {
                app.showMessage('ERROR: Authentication Service could not find     __RequestVerificationToken');
            }
            var tokenParam = "__RequestVerificationToken=" + encodeURIComponent(token);

            $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, options) {
                if (options.hasContent) {
                    options.data = options.data ? [options.data, tokenParam].join("&") :     tokenParam;
                }
            });
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: Hi Stuart,

Your idea is great, and I'm trying to apply it in my Hot Towel/Durandal project.  I got the auth and antiforgery services, but I'm not getting the auth service to intercept unauthorized users and redirect them to the login page.  How do I do that? do I need to add something to Index.cshtml?

Thanks

Comment: This is also on DurandalJs Google Group - there's been updates from other people on there and I've also added some code examples - they won't really fit in a comment here ... so ;-) .. here's the link  https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/durandaljs/iq9OPprfob0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I prefer to pass the antiforgery token in the header.  This way its easy to parse out of the request on the server because its not intermingled with your form's data.

I then created a custom action filter to check for the antiforgery token.

I [created a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416264/validateantiforgerytoken-with-spa-architecture/15512292#15512292) already on how to do this.

Comment: Cheers Evan, I hadn't thought about putting in the headers ( I  didn't see your post so thanks for the link)