# Alternative way to provide CSRF Token instead using @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, angular, csrf-protection

I'm working on an `angular 2` app using a `ASP.Net MVC` backend. For this, the `index.cshtml` has included `@Html.AntiForgeryToken();` so i get back a hidden input element with the Token as its value. In my frontend i can grab this token and use it for my requests. So far so good.

Now since user information is used to generate the token in the backend, i have to switch out the token on some occassions. The problem is described [here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970102/anti-forgery-token-is-meant-for-user-but-the-current-user-is-username).

Now since i don't want to do a full page reload in my app i have to use a workaround. For this i created a partial view in the backend which just hands out this input using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken();` as `ActionResult` with a simple method like this:

```
public ActionResult GetAntiForgery()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Home/AntiForgery.cshtml");
}
```

After login / logout i call this function from my frontend and replace the value of my existing `AntiForgery input element` like this:

```
getAntiForgery(url:string) {
        return this._http.get(url)
            .map((response:any) => {
                let originalXsrfElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]');
                let body = response._body;

                if(body) {
                    let helperElem = document.createElement('div');
                    helperElem.innerHTML = body;
                    let helperInputElem = <HTMLInputElement>helperElem.firstChild;
                    originalXsrfElement.value = helperInputElem.value;
                }

                return response;
            });
    }
```

I can't even tell you what bugs me the most. I hate to make an extra request (but lets not dive into this here) but way more terrible for me is that i have to request something, get an html string back and have to extract the token string out of it.

If i were the backend guy, i would kill the frontend guy (me..) for even thinking about creating an extra partial view, creating an extra method and always doing two requests on login/logout instead of one.

Is there a better way? For example i would like to call a method which just hands out a `JSON` with the proper token instead of an `HTML snippet`. Even better, on existing `JsonResult` methods in the backend, i would like to add the new `CSRF Token` as a property.

I'm not a backend architect so there might be some stuff wrong in general how i do this, but my backend colleagues don't mind what i'm doing there so it shouldn't be so far off.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this question might help (basically puts anti-forgery into ajax header instead of hidden field): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416264/validateantiforgerytoken-with-spa-architecture

Comment: Sorry, can't see how this helps with my problem. The question is different.

Comment: The "Anti-CSRF and AJAX" section in the linked article seems like it could be what you're looking for: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

Comment: Now i understand what you wanted to tell me, i thought we misunderstood each other. See my comment to the answer below for clarification where my issues are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AntiForgery.GetToken` in your action to set some property on the JSON being returned:

```
string cookieToken, formToken;
AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
json.RequestVerificationToken = cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
```

Then, pass it back in the header of your next AJAX request:

```
$.ajax("/my/awesome/url", {
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: { ... },
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': requestVerificationToken
    }
});
```

Since, it's no longer being handled by cookies, you can't just use the standard `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute. You'll need to manually check for the header and validate it. However, you should be able to create a custom attribute you can use instead:

```
AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenFromHeaderAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string cookieToken = "";
        string formToken = "";

        IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
        {
            string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
            if (tokens.Length == 2)
            {
                cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
                formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
            }
        }
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
    }
}
```

Then, just decorate your actions with `[ValidateAntiForgeryTokenFromHeader]` instead.

*[Code adapted from http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks]*

Comment: What i don't get is, the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` call inserts a html snippet, an input with the token as a value. Does this already setup the cookie or why doesn't your suggestion work with cookies anymore? What i want is just to get the value of `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and send this string value as a json response instead handing out a view. Your approach seems to be a bit of an overkill for me just for this little "change". Like "Frontend: Server, give me that token string". "Server: No sorry i can only give you an html element...". Wait, what? ;)

Comment: Typically anything you'd hit via an AJAX request wouldn't support cookies. A well-designed API is going to be REST-based, and REST is stateless (no session, no cookies). Web Api, for sure doesn't support it.